# How to rejoin consul clients to server after server restart?

Tags: consul

I have started server (single node).
And joined client.

```
# consul members
Node                   Address             Status  Type    Build  Protocol  DC
v-ansible              172.16.10.11:8301   alive   server  0.5.2  2         dc1
v-php-cron             172.16.10.217:8301  alive   client  0.5.2  2         dc1
```

Then I restart server.
And on server I see:

```
# consul members
Node                   Address            Status  Type    Build  Protocol  DC
v-ansible              172.16.10.11:8301  alive   server  0.5.2  2         dc1
```

On client:

```
# consul members
Node                   Address             Status  Type    Build  Protocol  DC
v-php-cron             172.16.10.217:8301  alive   client  0.5.2  2         dc1
v-ansible              172.16.10.11:8301   left    server  0.5.2  2         dc1
```

An in client logs:

```
2015/11/05 17:35:05 [INFO] consul: adding server v-ansible (Addr: 172.16.10.11:8300) (DC: dc1)
2015/11/05 17:38:14 [INFO] serf: EventMemberLeave: v-ansible 172.16.10.11
2015/11/05 17:38:14 [INFO] consul: removing server v-ansible (Addr: 172.16.10.11:8300) (DC: dc1)
2015/11/05 17:39:45 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No known Consul servers
2015/11/05 17:40:11 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No known Consul servers
2015/11/05 17:40:30 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No known Consul servers
```

Why server stay in left Status?
How can I rejoin clients to server automatically ?

Comment: Did you use -bootstrap-expect option for server?

Comment: Yes.
This is config on server:
{
  "service": {"name": "ansible"},
  "server": true,
  "bootstrap_expect": 1,
  "data_dir": "/var/lib/consul"
}

Answer (score 0):

skip_leave_on_interrupt option solved my problem.
Server sent LEAVE during restart to cluster if skip_leave_on_interrupt=True (Default)

Comment: This is option for what..? And you did what, set it to False..? Can you be more specific???